# Is "where" in "place where" redundant?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Example sentence:

> We're heading to the place (where) you're going to have your next
> challenge.

Is *where* redundant in situations like this? Why or why not?

Comment: In your example, ***where*** actually *means* the same as *[at] **the place***. Just as ***when*** refers to / means *[at] **the time*** in a context like *I'll meet you in the station **at the time when** your train arrives*. In principle you can include both elements - but it's unnecessary, and usually we just use one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people would assume the **where** if it were omitted.

But without it, the two statements: **We're heading to the place** and **you're going to have your next challenge** are linked only by implication. In written texts, punctuation would make things clearer.

You could describe numerous situations in which the two statements would not be linked at all. Context would normally give people a clue. So yes, it is required for the sake of clarity.

The same applies in examples (depending on the punctuation) such as:

**Tomorrow is the day (when) you'll meet your father.**

Listeners would understand the **when** to be elided but, without context, room remains for doubt.